# YouTube API v3 totalResults field is returning 1 000 000 when it shoudn't

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

1) I'm using YouTube API v3 and when i send this request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&type=video&key=MY_KEY&maxResults=50&publishedAfter=2013-09-02T17:00:01Z
```

It's returing me   "totalResults": 1000000

I don't think that from 17:00:00 was added 1 000 000 movies.
Also when i jump to page #2 using pageToken i'm getting:

"totalResults": 46269

What's going on?

2) Let's say that my search request has returned 1 000 000 totalResults.
How far i can travel using pageToken?

Answer (score 1):

"totalResults" is an estimation and its value can change on the next page call. The limit for searches with version 2 is 1000. I suppose the limit will be the same with version 3.

Comment: Estimate - ok but between 1 000 000 and 46269 is a big difference.

Comment: I can agree with that. But nothing we can do to change that.

Comment: Hello @Als what do you mean the limit for searches is 1000? You mean that the number of next page tokens totally provides you 1000 results?

Comment: Yes. However, now the total results seems to have been reduced to 500. To get more, try using different parameters, vary the query tags and keep track of getting different video id's returned.