# Why limited number of next page tokens?

Tags: youtube-api

Through a script I can collect a sequence of videos that `search list` returns. The `maxresults` variable was set to 50. The total number items are big in number but the number of next page tokens are not enough to retrieve all the desired results. Is there any way to take all the returned items or it is YouTube restricted?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, retrieving the results of a search is limited in size.
The total results that you are allowed to retrieve seems to have been reduced to 500 (in the past it was limited to 1000). The api does not allow you to retrieve more from a query. To try to get more, try using a number of queries with different parameters, like: publishedAfter, publishedBefore, order, type, videoCategoryId, or vary the query tags and keep track of getting different video id's returned.

See for a reference:
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4282

BTW. "totalResults" is an estimation and its value can change on the next page call.
See: [YouTube API v3 totalResults field is returning 1 000 000 when it shoudn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580384/youtube-api-v3-totalresults-field-is-returning-1-000-000-when-it-shoudnt/18581652?noredirect=1#comment36469547_18581652)