# TotalResults returning a wrong value on YouTube API v3

Tags: youtube-api

I'm working on a migration from YouTube API v2 to API v3. I found that this version limits the number of results to 500. To deal with this, I'm writting some code to split the query into more specific sub-queries. To know if I have to split or not, I'm looking on totalResults attribute. So, if totalResults is greather than 500, I proceed to split the query. The problem is that totalResults attribute in the response is returning a value that is not correct. For example, I have a response that retrieves 38 items (only one page), but when I look at totalResults attribute, it has a value of 678, which is not the expected value (38).

Does anybody know if this is a bug on the API or if there is another way to know the total amount of items with more precission?

Thanks in advice

Comment: Take a look: [youtube api v3 totalresults field is returning 1 000 000 when it shoudnt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580384/youtube-api-v3-totalresults-field-is-returning-1-000-000-when-it-shoudnt)

Comment: Hi kums! I saw that post and it saids that total results is an estimation. But in my case, that estimation is really too different from the correct value in all the cases. That's why I found it really strange. Thanks for help!